# how to get text with xpath from bad xml?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a "bad xml structure" file:

```
<cars>
    <car>Toyota
        <country>Japan</coutry>
        ....
    </car>
</cars>
```

How to correctly get the right word (*Toyota*) using Xpath?
I tried:

`<xsl:value-of select = "cars/car/text()"/>`.

It works, but I think there are more appropriate methods.
Thanks.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two alternative solutions and recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/cars/car/text()[1]
```

**or if you want to discard most of the white space in the text node selected above, use:**

```
normalize-space(/cars/car/text()[1])
```

Do note that while in XSLT 1.0 `<xsl:value-of>` outputs the string valu only of the first node of the node-set selected by the expression in the `select` attribute, `<xsl:copy-of>` will output all the nodes in the node-set. In XSLT 2.0 even `<xsl:value-of>` outputs all the nodes in the node-set.

Therefore, for purposes of portability, upgradability and simply for avoiding errors, it is better to specify which exactlyy node from the nodeset is to be output -- even when using `<xsl:value-of>`

Comment: Thank you for your fast and detailed response.